# Source code of HashMap.java

Tags: java, java-6

I need to look at the source code of HashMap.java of JDK version 1.6.0_19.
I searched the web  but could not find anywhere.
Any pointers is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u19-oth-JPR)? You can download the full JDK, and the sources are usually distributed with the JDK.

Comment: Why does it have to be v19 specifically? Are you having an issue with it - if so, how do you know it to be exactly v19?

Comment: @josh.trow wouldn't he know by the version of Java he is using?

Comment: @Laf +1 for the link, thats very helpful.

Comment: @MiserableVariable: I suppose so yes - Gimme a break, it's FRIDAY :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download that version of the JDK. The source code is provided in a src.zip file.

Comment: Not every jdk version ships with src.zip

Answer (score 1):

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java

Comment: GrepCode shows `503 Service Unavailable`. Now we need to use either zGrepCode or DocJar

Comment: Link seams to be dead (503 _Service Unavailable_)

Answer (score 0):

Try here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6

Answer (score 0):

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Aqua: Standards have to be maintained, but rather than copy and pasting standards why not propose a solution. ie. How do you answer "Where can I find source code?" without a link?

Comment: @porcoesphino see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143663) meta discussion.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the link :P
I'm still curious why you recommended it for deletion. There's no such thing as a rule that should be blindly followed. In this case the answer provides useful information for finding an online copy of the source code even if the link becomes invalid.

Comment: @porcoesphino The link points to a wrong (Java 7) version of `HashMap` and does not actually answer the question.  I find the accepted answer in this thread much more useful, even though it has no links. There is no rule.  Link-only answers present a controversial topic and unfortunately there no single solution that fits all. Look at many Meta discussions why link-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: @porcoesphino: "How do you answer 'Where can I find source code?' without a link?" You don't answer it. You flag it for closure. Questions that are necessarily answered with links can't survive on their own.

Answer (score 0):

Agree to the "download jdk", if you want to see it in your eclipse, you can edit it as the source of the jdk, then when you type HashMap, press F3, you will go to the HashMap.java.