# how to check definition of builtin functions of java in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

How we can check code of built-in function using eclipse.
For example: if I want to look for code for map.put() builtin function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Source code of HashMap.java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437932/source-code-of-hashmap-java)

Comment: you need map the java source code which would be available in jdk installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by following the below steps

Press CTRL, hover the cursor on the function name, click it (Windows)

Press command, hover the cursor on the function name, click it (MAC)